# Редактирование записей таблиц базы данных

Tags: jdbc, sql

Привет, ХешКод.

У меня вопрос такого вот плана:

возможно каким-то образом или комбинацией SQL запросов изменить или вообще заменить значение записи таблицы, при этом чтобы эта запись оставалась на своем месте? Проблема с запросом `INSERT` состоит в том, что он добавляет записи в конец таблицы, а мне нужно чтобы запись оставалась на своем месте.

Или вообще возможность не добавлять записи в конец таблицы, а вставлять его между определенными двумя известными заранее записями? Это тоже могло бы решить мою проблему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если **INSERT** , то это значит, что добавляется новая запись и это совсем не клеется с "*а мне нужно чтобы запись оставалась на своем месте.*", т.к. у неё не было "своего места". Если редактируется запись (**UPDATE**), то она остается на "своём месте" по умолчанию. Что ж вас конкретно беспокоит?

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, только еще один вопрос:

 "UPDATE myTable SET  Address='New York' WHERE Name='John' AND Address='New Orlean' AND Course='M.Tech'";

такая запись исполнится корректно?

заменится New Orlean на  New York?

Comment: Да, но вы уже наверно и сами проверили ))